# After PHP 7.4.14 Update I have some SQL errors

Tags: php, pdo

After update of PHP at 6.1.2021 from 7.4.13 to 7.4.14 I have some errors which was not before. MySql is 5.7.32. I have sqls thru:

```
$prep = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
$prep->execute();
```

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1; Query:SET
> collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

> 1115 Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'; Query:SET
> character_set_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'SESSION sql_mode =
> "NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUT' at line
> 1; Query:SESSION sql_mode =
> "NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

On my server at same day was updated also PHP 7.3 to 7.3.26. Same scripts running on 7.3 has no problems.

Before this update was everything OK.

Comment: Yep, weird.  Looks like a PDO issue.  I have encountered similar issues when setting the `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES , 1);`.  It is not the value of the attribute that caused the issue, it was setting the attribute.   If you have that , either as a `setAttribute` line, or as part of the connection parameters, remove it and get MySql's opinion on the query.

Comment: My settings are thru sqls.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a script that creates a mysql connection
with the charset.  **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**

And your mysql does not know this charset.

```
1115 Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'; Query:SET character_set_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Solutions:
Edit the connection string.

Comment: I know what it means but how you explain that before this update was all OK? In my connection is nothing about charset because I set it later by SQL.

Comment: There are a quite some posts here in SO that point out to changed behaviour after upgrade to php 7.   Where suddenly  wrong characters appeared or other nasty stuff. 

Please look into the file where you get the error.

Comment: no posts about update from 7.4.13 to 7.4.14

Comment: You did not mention  from which version you upgraded.  But look into the connection strings of your software.

Comment: I see that you dont understand what am I talking about. PHP code is same without changes. Before 6.1.2021 PHP version was 7.4.13 and everything was OK, after auto update of my PHP to 7.4.14 at 6.1.2021 has PDO problems to set charsets. Please dont loose your and my time when you exact dont know what is the problem. Thank you. I know that you want help but I am asking after I investigate many hours of the problem.

Comment: I do understand the problem.  
You have 2 choices - report this as a bug to the php developer team and wait 3 or more weeks to 7.4.14 or later  or change the connection string now and have it up and running this evening.   Your choice. :-B